# Copy File's Parent directory path from context menu

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am learning batch scripting since it's very useful for setting some quick custom context menu options of Windows user's choice to get file and it's parent directory's path.

Now I know following command to get the passed argument as file path and copy it to clipboard:

```dos
cmd /c (echo.|set /p=""%1"") | clip
```

But then why isn't following syntax working as expected when set in Context menu ?

```dos
cmd /c (echo.|set /p=""%~dp1"") | clip
```

Is it a variable expansion issue ? Please guide as to why it isn't working and how to resolve it so that it expands properly.

Sample of registry entry wherein I am permanently setting the command to be run, with switches, variable expansions etc.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy File's Parent Path]
@="Copy File's Parent Path"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy File's Parent Path\Command]
@="cmd.exe /c (echo.|set /p=\"\"%~dp1\"\") | clip"
```

Comment: Try using the `%~dp0` rather then `%~dp1` as the syntax of the command is `%~dpI` with `I` is a placeholder for the variable index. `0` = the calling file, `1` = argument #1, `2` = argument #2, etc... Better explanation here: https://htipe.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/the-dp0-variable/

Comment: I need the directory path of the argument #1(filepath) file and not the calling file.

Comment: Why are you using two sets of double quotes?

Comment: It is a way to escape the quotes especially when you're passing the command in the registry "Command" key which stores the command string like `@="<command>"`.

Comment: Please provide a code example in your question.

Comment: You mean registry file example ?

Comment: Well I am not sure how we can resolve the problem without seeing the registry entry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176450/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-squashman).

Comment: 1. To get the file path use `%~f1` rather than `%1`. 2. Why are you double-double-quoting the path? I would just do `cmd /C < nul set /P ="%~f1" | clip` to get the unquoted path into the clipcoard; your quotation style could cause trouble with some special characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables like `%1`, `%*`, `%V` in registry, are placeholders which will be resolve and replaced by Windows Shell component (Win32 Shell). They just happened to be similar to the variables that is used by Windows Command Processor(CMD.EXE) at Command Prompt or in batch files, But they are in no way related to each other.

For instance with CMD.EXE `%1` can only be used within batch files it has no meaning at Command Prompt or when passed as a command by `/C` or `/K` switch. In your registry sample `%1` will be resolved by Windows Shell not by CMD.EXE so you can not use things like `%~dp0` or `%~dp1` in registry, They have no meaning to Windows Shell.

So you have to take `%1` by CMD.EXE (which have been automatically replaced by its actual value) and do processing with it in a `FOR` loop to obtain the directory path of the file.

This is the actual command that will extract path information from file name:

```
cmd.exe /e:on /d /s /c "for %%a in ("%1") do @(set /p "=%%~dpa")<nul | clip"
```

It can be entered as is, in Registry Editor to the `(default)` value of the appropriate Key e.g: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy Path to clipboard\Command` for current user or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy Path to clipboard\Command` for all users.

And the string for registry script:

```
@="cmd.exe /e:on /d /s /c \"for %%a in (\"%1\") do @(set /p \"=%%~dpa\")<nul | clip\""
```

A sample `.REG` script will look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy Path to clipboard\Command]
@="cmd.exe /e:on /d /s /c \"for %%a in (\"%1\") do @(set /p \"=%%~dpa\")<nul | clip\""
```

When you want to pass a string that contains percents(`%`) you have to escape the percents by doubling them, pretty much the same as you do in batch files.

Comment: It worked so perfectly right, it even gave the path without quotes, which was charm working for me and astonishingly it was simple enough. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy Files Path\command]
@="cmd /c (echo. | set /p =\"\"%1\"\") | clip"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Copy Files Parent Path\command]
@="cmd /c (echo. | set /p =\"\"%w\"\") | clip"
```

Replace `%1` with `%w`. 2 registry entries to demonstrate
`%1` as `Copy Files Path` and `%w` as `Copy Files Parent Path`.

Reference from [Extending Shortcut Menus](https://web.archive.org/web/20111002101214/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101(v=vs.85).aspx) at the bottom of the page.

> ```
> %0 or %1  the first file parameter. For example “C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\New Text Document.txt”. Generally this should be in quotes and the applications command line parsing should accept quotes to disambiguate files with spaces in the name and different command line parameters (this is a security best practice and I believe mentioned in MSDN).
> %N  (where N is 2 - 9), replace with the nth parameter
> %*  replace with all parameters
> %~  replace with all parameters starting with and following the second parameter
> %d  desktop absolute parsing name of the first parameter (for items that don’t have file system paths)
> %h  hotkey value
> %i  IDList stored in a shared memory handle is passed here.
> %l  long file name form of the first parameter. Note win32 applications will be passed the long file name, win16 applications get the short file name. Specifying %L is preferred as it avoids the need to probe for the application type.
> %s  show command
> %v  for verbs that are none implies all, if there is no parameter passed this is the working directory
> %w  the working directory
> ```

Comment: Nice one with a good explanation, I wasn't aware about %w till now.

Answer (score 2):

**`%W`**, *which generally holds the working directory*, when you right click on a file, would be the files' parent.

You could therefore try this:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\HoldParent]
@="Parent to Clipboard"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\HoldParent\command]
@="Cmd /C \"Echo %W|Clip\""
```

*You could extend this a little for potential unicode/character issues, but in general it should perfom as required without.*

**Edit**

To extend it a little, *(including no newline)*, perhaps:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\HoldParent]
@="Parent to Clipboard"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\HoldParent\command]
@="Cmd /Q /D /U /C \"Set/P \"=%W\"<Nul|Clip\""
```