# Windows 10 batch script working directory for folder right click menu

Tags: batch-file

What I would like to do is I need to create a folder with today date as its name for archiving purposes. So I created a script to do that and it is working. Now I want to add this script batch file to the folder right click menu so that I can click on it and it will create that folder automatically where I clicked.  So I created a key in my registry as follow:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Today Directory script]
@="&Today Directory script"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Today Directory script\command]
@="C:\\Scripts\\TodayDir.bat \"%V\""
```

Now the command appears in the menu.

[Image of right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU6UO.png)

here is the code of the script:

```
@ECHO OFF 

REM Gets the working folder from where the click came from and removes the last slash (\)
for %%Q in ("%~dp1\.") DO set "mypath=%%~fQ"

REM Checks when the wroking directory is from. Local drive or network drive
if %mypath:~0,1%==c (goto cdrive) else ( goto networkdrive)

REM Code to create directory in a local drive
:cdrive
MD %mypath%\%DATE%
exit

REM Code to create directory in a network drive by assigning a drive letter to the path,
REM  create the directory, delete the drive assigment.
:networkdrive
net use p: "%mypath%"
MD p:\%DATE%
net use p: /delete
exit
```

This code is working OK but not when it is triggered from the right click menu from above. It does not get the path of the working directory (`"%~dp1\."` command). If I do `"%~dp0\."` I get the path of where the batch file is located (C:\Scrpits).

How do I get the directory where the click came from from the right click menu?

Thanks,

Denis

New info:

This is the registry key that was created:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Easy Context Menu\EcMenu.exe" /RunAdmin "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe" /s /k pushd "%V"
```

When the cmd.exe shell opens I get this mwssage:
`'\\lofthouse1\Tool' CMD.exe was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to windows directory.`

What do I need to change the registry to to get cmd.exe to accept the pushd directrory name?

Denis

Comment: Take a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452418/copy-files-parent-directory-path-from-context-menu)

Comment: `@=cmd /c "C:\\Scripts\\TodayDir.bat" "%~1"`?