# Cannot return value of "%~n1" from %1 argument (filename from path)

Tags: batch-file, arguments, command

I'm trying to add a rule (name) to the firewall by this command in the registry (context menu):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Firewall\shell\Block\command]
@="netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"%~n1\" dir=out action=block program=\"%1\""
```

%1 is the path name of the program which is returned just fine.

For some reason, I cannot get the "%~n1" part right. It just returns "%~n1" instead of filename without extension.

What is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot use the command modifiers in the registry.

Comment: I think what you probably want there is `%L`.

Comment: Here is the reference of the [Context Menu variables](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context) you can use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy File's Parent directory path from context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452418/copy-files-parent-directory-path-from-context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

@Squashman thanks, I ended up using cmd.exe which actually gives access to the %~n part, like this

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Firewall\shell\Block\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /c for %%a in (\"%1\") do netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"%%~na\" dir=out action=block program=\"%1\""
```

With the benefit of being able to return more than one element with "for"...